# What is the difference between a type alias and a tuple struct?

Tags: struct, types, rust

What is the difference between

```
type CMoves = Vec<Move>;
```

and

```
struct CMoves(Vec<Move>);
```

I understand I can implement traits with the second one, but I cannot with the first one as `Vec` is defined outside of my crate. Are there any other differences, for example with memory representation?

Comment: [_"There’s no runtime performance penalty for using this pattern (the newtype pattern). The wrapper type is elided at compile time."_](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#the-newtype-pattern-to-implement-external-traits-on-external-types)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware it was a pattern.

Comment: Memory layout is the same in practice.

Answer (score 7):

A type alias is just that, an alias. Pure *syntactic* sugar with no bearing on semantics. For all intents and purposes you could just replace all of the alias name with what it aliases.

On the other hand, a tuple struct is an entirely separate type, with all that entails:

- you define its invariants,
- you define which functions it implements,
- you define which traits it implements.

As such, the two are nothing alike.